# Adaptive streaming support in Android's MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I want to write a simple video player in Android that supports adaptive streaming through `MPEG-DASH`. Does the latest Android `MediaPlayer` API now support MPEG-DASH? Until a few years ago I remember only option was to use `ExoPlayer`. I would prefer using the basic MediaPlayer for simplicity.

```
// Create a player instance.
SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
// Set the media item to be played.
player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(dashUri));
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare();
```

Comment: Adaptive streaming can get quite complicated, especially with encrypted content and if you want user control via the UI. ExoPlayer is pretty much the defacto standard player on Android now and is pretty reliable in general so I may be easiest to use it if you can.

Comment: Thanks. I thought its API is very difficult to use. But looks like it's not.. I'll try to use it :)